# custom action notification icons in just audio

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

How can I give notification icons optional functionality?

In addition to the normal function of the icons, I want to give other optional functions to the icons
For example, after the next hit, another function is executed and ..

**In fact, I want to listen to the changes of the main actions (next, previous, pause ..)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the official audio_service example, specifically [example/lib/example_multiple_handlers.dart](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/tree/master/audio_service/example/lib), you will find it defines the `skipToQueueItem` method to do "normal functions" like seeking to the requested item:

```dart
  @override
  Future<void> skipToQueueItem(int index) async {
    // Then default implementations of skipToNext and skipToPrevious provided by
    // the [QueueHandler] mixin will delegate to this method.
    if (index < 0 || index >= queue.value.length) return;
    // This jumps to the beginning of the queue item at newIndex.
    _player.seek(Duration.zero, index: index);
    // Demonstrate custom events.
    customEvent.add('skip to $index');
  }
```

If you want to do custom things, just add your custom code at the end of this method. Note that in the example, the callbacks for `skipToNext` and `skipToPrevious` just delegate to the above method so that skipping to a track is handled in this one place above.

> In fact, I want to listen to the changes of the main actions (next, previous, pause ..)

The approach is exactly the same. Just override each of these callbacks and handle each one to first do the "normal functions" followed by your custom code.

For example, you can override `skipToNext` like this:

```dart
@override
Future<void> skipToNext() async {
  // Do the normal functions
  await _player.seekToNext();
  // Add your custom code here
}
```

The approach is identical for every callback, so all you need to do is look at the documentation to see a list of all of the callbacks available (e.g. `pause`) and then override each one that you need and implement it using the above approach. First, do the normal functions, followed by your custom code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but  In fact, I want to listen to the changes of the main actions (next, previous, pause ..)

Comment: You get the idea, though, right? If you override `skipToNext` and `skipToPrevious` in the same way, you can listen to those methods directly.

Comment: I've updated the answer to do `skipToNext`. It's the same approach again. If you want to do another callback, e.g. `pause`, it will be an identical approach again, so hopefully my answer gives you the general idea, you just need to implement the same approach for all of the individual callbacks that you want to handle in your app.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, 
But this code does not work for notification actions (next, previous)

Comment: If you add that `skipToNext` method to the example, it works as intended.

Comment: next & prev is already there, but how i can add more custom action button on notification audio player, for example used of like button?

Comment: This question, despite the title, was about handling the main actions, not custom actions, so you'll need to create a separate question.